# Problem centering a block of images with horizontal panel

Tags: gwt, uibinder

Well, like the title says I am trying to center a block of images in a horizontal panel to look something like

|-------iiiii------|

where |'s are screen borders, and i's are all images next to each other

I've been trying to use variations of something like

```
<ui:style>
....
.hPanel { display:block; }
</ui:style>
....
<g:HorizontalPanel width='100%' horizontalAlignment='ALIGN_CENTER' addStyleNames="{style.hPanel}" >
<g:Image resource="{icons.a}" ui:field="a"/>
<g:Image resource="{icons.b}" ui:field="b"/>
<g:Image resource="{icons.c}" ui:field="c"/>
<g:Image resource="{icons.d}" ui:field="d"/>
<g:Image resource="{icons.e}" ui:field="e"/>
</g:HorizontalPanel>
```

Also with other things such as putting margin-left and margin-right to auto, but the only results I am getting is either
|iiiii-------| or |--i--i--i--i--i--| (if i take out display:block)

Comment: Try removing the width='100%' and then setting margin-left and margin-right to auto.

Comment: Actually it seems that all this time it was only not centering on chrome, although centering fine on IE and firefox...

Answer (score 0):

Aaahhh, the old centered div (without fixed width) problem. There are many solutions, but they    work with various success on different browsers.

The only one that worked for me on all browsers was a list (`<ul><li>`) with a left and right of 50%.

You put your data inside the `<li></li>`

```
#parent {
    width: 100%;
}

#parent ul {
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    left: 50%;
    padding: 0
}

#parent ul li {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    right: 50%;
    padding: 0;
}
```